# Java/JavaScript - java.time.Instant serialization to javascript Date

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a web API endpoint that accepts a `java.time.Instant` instance, like so:

```
{ "time": "2015-07-23T10:31:33Z" }
```

When I get a response back, I get this:

```
{ "time": 1437647493 }
```

When I try to create a new `Date` instance in JavaScript like this:

```
new Date(1437647493);
```

I get this result:

```
Sat Jan 17 1970 15:20:47 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

What is the relationship between `"2015-07-23T10:31:33Z"` and `1437647493` and how do I parse the result to JavaScript's `Date`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1437647493 is the number of **seconds** since January 1, 1970. This is commonly known as a UNIX timestamp, and that date is the UNIX epoch.

`Date` expects the number of **milliseconds** since the UNIX epoch. Multiply by 1000 and you'll get the time you want.

```
new Date(1437647493L * 1000)
```

Or, in Java if you're using `Instant`, write:

```java
Instant.ofEpochSecond(1437647493L)
```